# Error in socket.connect() in Android Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-studio, bluetooth

I am new to Android programming. I am trying to connect two android mobiles through bluetooth. I am using android 4.4.4 in one mobile and android 6 in another. And I am using Windows 7, Android Studio.

Code-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button openButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.open);
    Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    Button closeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.close);
    myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    myTextbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.entry);

    //Open Button
    openButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                findBT();
                openBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Send Button
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                sendData();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });

    //Close button
    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try 
            {
                closeBT();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { }
        }
    });
}

void findBT()
{
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
    {
        myLabel.setText("No bluetooth adapter available");
    }

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
    {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
    {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            if(device.getName().equals("motoG")) 
            {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Device Found");
}

void openBT() throws IOException
{
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);  
    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); 
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();

    beginListenForData();

    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");
}

void beginListenForData()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    final byte delimiter = 10; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character

    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                
           while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
           {
                try 
                {
                    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();                        
                    if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++)
                        {
                            byte b = packetBytes[i];
                            if(b == delimiter)
                            {
     byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
     System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
     final String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");
     readBufferPosition = 0;

                                handler.post(new Runnable()
                                {
                                    public void run()
                                    {
                                        myLabel.setText(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    stopWorker = true;
                }
           }
        }
    });

    workerThread.start();
}

void sendData() throws IOException
{
    String msg = myTextbox.getText().toString();
    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
}

void closeBT() throws IOException
{
    stopWorker = true;
    mmOutputStream.close();
    mmInputStream.close();
    mmSocket.close();
    myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Closed");
}
}
```

Error- In .connect(), I am getting an exception -

1. read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1.
2. getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
3. connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[55]}

I tried using insecureRFcom, it din't work. I re-paired my device, but didn't work. I removed all other paired devices from mobile, it din't work. I looked around this website and tried many approaches, but nothing works. Hope someone can help me figure out the problem.

Comment: If you're going to ignore `IOExceptions` how do you ever expect to debug your code?

Comment: @EJP I have ignored it just here. I have written it in my code. If you look at the bottom of my main post ( first point) , I have mentioned the exceptions there.